# Check if functions are independent

Tags: linear-algebra, independence

So I recently learned about how to check whether functions are independent. 
As far as I understood it one of the methods is to plug in freely chosen values for x and you can calculate the determinate for the matrix that results from that.
$$ f_1(x), f_2(x), f_3(x)$$ 
$$\begin{vmatrix}
f_1(x_1) & f_2(x_1) & f_3(x_1)\\
f_1(x_2) & f_2(x_2) & f_3(x_2)\\
f_1(x_3) & f_2(x_3) & f_3(x_3)\\
\end{vmatrix}$$

Where $x_1, x_2, x_3$ are the three values I chose for $x$. 
I don't doubt my Professor but for me its still feels kinda "unmathy" if I might call it that way. So I was going to ask whether this a legit strategy or only works in certain scenarios.

Given that I have functions $f_1=\cos^2x$, $f_2=\sin^2ax$, $f_3=1$.
And I choose $x_1=0$, $x_2=\pi/2$ $x_3=\pi$

$$\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1\\
0 & \sin^2\frac{a\pi}{2} & 1\\
1 & \sin^2a\pi &1\\
\end{vmatrix}$$

and the determinant would be $\sin^2a\pi$, so for each $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ the three functions would be dependent. 
However I could also chose different value for the $x_1$... and I would get a different determinant

Comment: This will find linearly dependent functions each time but it may also suggest that linearly independent functions are linearly dependent. You may have been talking about polynomials only; in the case of checking whether $n$ polynomials of degree at most $n-1$ are linearly independent, this method will always work.

Comment: The criterion is that the functions are inedependent iff for every choice of $x_1,x_2,x_3$ the determinant is zero. If you have second-degree polynomials, as you said, you only need to check it for one triple (ehere all three are distinct, of course).

Comment: I edited my question to be more precies

Answer (score 1):

Possibly the professor lied; more likely he/she didn't say what you thought he/she said.

**In fact** if that determinant is non-zero then the functions are independent. But that only goes one way - if the determinant is zero that does *not* imply the functions are dependent.

(As commented, if the determinant is zero for *every* choice of $x_1,x_2,x_3$ then the functions are dependent. That's possibly not that useful as a "test", since it might take a while to check every one of the infinitely many possibilities.)

Comment: But if the functions are independent than they have a non zero determinant right?
So if the determinant is zero they must be dependent. Or am I confusing it with the independece of vectors.

Comment: You're confusing something. Say $f(t)=t$ and $g(t)=t^2$. What do you mean by "the determinant of $f$ and $g$", exactly?

Comment: **Note**:  If $f(t)=t$ and $g(t)=t^2$ then the determinant of the _matrix_ $\begin{bmatrix}f(x_1)&g(x_1)\\f(x_2)&g(x_2)\end{bmatrix}$ can be zero or non-zero, depending on the choice of $x_1$ and $x_2$..

Comment: Sorry I meant to ask whether when determinant of the matrix you obtain when plugging in values for $x_1$... .I am really struggling to find the answer for that problem

Comment: That question is answered in the Answer I posted! Let $f(t)=t$ and $g(t)=t^2$. _Are_ $f$ and $g$ dependent? Now let $x_1=0$ and $x_2=1$; what is the determinant of that matrix?